# Handling payload with multiple fields data while consuming soap service in groovy/grails?

Tags: grails, soap, groovy

I have to handle  payload with multiple fields (i.e. 4 of types : e.g. string>50 chars, image url, number and boolean) data while consuming soap service.

Please give me a advice or any example on SOAP service. I'm new to this concept so please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy has a nice SOAPClient class that goes something like this...

```
import groovy.net.soap.SoapClient

def proxy = new SoapClient("http://someurl.com/SayHelloServiceInterface?wsdl")

def result = proxy.sayHello("Mike"); <-- the method name would be from SOAP service
assert (result == "Hello Mike");
```

You can get more information [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+SOAP) and learn about it's dependencies.